# How to 'Spread navigation bar contents wider?'

Tags: html, css

Still learning css...

I've just got one major issue..

My nav-bar is currently squished. I'm not sure how to space out the text away from each other to go wider, so it takes up more space.

I have tried using the following (got it from similar post as mine):

```
justify-content: space-between
```

but that didn't work.

Lastly, (just a random trick Id like to learn )if you know how to do it..
How would I separate the two sides from the logo to be pushed away to left and right? As an example..

All content from the left side of the logo, is showing from the edge of the left screen and vice versa for the right side. But the logo remains in the middle. And all text remains horizontal.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
}

img{
  height: 30px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;

}

.nav li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;

}

.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css" type="text/css">


  </head>
  <body>



<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
  <li><img src="logo.png"></li>

  <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>





  </body>

<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest a slow and thorough read through this [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You can't implement `justify-content` without a flex container.

Comment: Thank you! great recommendation

Comment: Btw, there's two closing `</ul>` tags in your code when there should only be one - you should check if that error is also in your original code or only in this code excerpt due to copy/paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `justify-content`, you need to set `display: flex` on the parent element first. I'd also suggest not to use `justify-content: space-between` but `justify-content: space-around` while resetting the default left padding of the `<ul>` to get even spacing. Alternatively, set the right padding to an equal value while using `justify-content: space-between`.

In order to have the logo take up more space and the menu items to be "pushed" to the sides, just set the logo's `<li>` to something like 50% width, flex layout will take care of the rest. I added a class "logo" to the element in order to achieve that.

**Update:** About keeping the menu items centered horizontally, you can achieve that by using `align-items: center` on the flex container.

**Update2:** I've also added in an example pushing the items as far to the sides as possible by setting the logo width to 100% and a margin of 10px between the elements, as well as a 15px padding to the menu bar itself.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
}

img{
  height: 30px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;

}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav2 .logo {
  width: 50%;
}

.nav3 {
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav3 .logo {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav3 li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav3 li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.nav4 ul {
  align-items: center;
}

.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
  
  <li class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></li>

  <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p>Pushing the menu items aside:</p>
<div class="nav nav2">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
  
  <li class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></li>

  <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p>Pushing the items as far aside as possible, with a fixed-width spacing:</p>
<div class="nav nav3">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
  
  <li class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></li>

  <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p>Nav items centered horizontally:</p>
<div class="nav nav4">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
  
  <li class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></li>

  <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response

Answer (score 1):

In this case .nav ul has been set as a flex-container with display:flex;
Rather than using space-around, I have added a class to the logo and set the flex property to 1 (flex: 1). This pushes the left/right nav items apart and the logo expands to take up the remaining space.

.nav li items has been given a bit of padding so they aren't squished together.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
}

img{
  height: 30px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav ul {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.nav li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.logo {
  flex:1;
}

.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
    <li class='logo'><img src="logo.png"></li>

    <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```